# How can I set gcc 4.9.2 as my compiler for Xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am learning C, using my mac to code right now.

Currently I am using gcc version 4.9.2  (found by going gcc --version) on terminal. However this is when I am connected to my school server.

When I am not connected I get some random things with Xcode etc etc...

Question is in Xcode, my default compiler is Apple LLVM 7.0, and there is no option in the dropdown box to change it to a gcc compiler.

I am wondering how I can change the compiler on Xcode from LLVM to gcc...

Thanks all !

Comment: `OS X` no longer uses gcc, it uses clang. If you want to use gcc then you'll either need to compile and build it, or install via macports or homebrew.